# Sports Collectibles - On Topic for Sports SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

A previously untapped topic on Sports SE is sports collectibles.

---

Several questions have come up with this subject:

[What factors should I consider toward keeping sports cards in mint condition?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/what-factors-should-i-consider-toward-keeping-sports-cards-in-mint-condition).

[How should baseball card commons be stored?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-should-baseball-card-commons-be-stored)

https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/how-much-would-a-gold-rookie-card-for-an-unknown-hockey-player-be-worth

---

**Would sports collectibles be on-topic for Sports SE? Why or why not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we are scoped ***anything directly related to sports participation or fandom is on topic*** which means quite clearly that sports collecting should be on topic.

Sports collecting is an important part of fandom and leaving it out would be a disservice to those of us who got here via the original sports proposal and are here predominantly for the fan aspects of this site.

Comment: so, on sports.SE, the posts not-only about sports but also about sports fans' activities are on topic, is it so?

Comment: @SportsFan yes.